# How to get access to phone book of device which is connected using Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth, android-source

I want to pull contacts from device which is connected using Bluetooth.

How can I do this?

As I understand, I have to use Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP). 
But there is no public api for using it in Android sdk.

I see only `BluetoothPbapClient.java` but it's marked as `@hide` and no methods to get contacts there.

Comment: You will probably have to implement it on the lower-level yourself, but still you should know that the user will have to go to Bluetooth Settings, and enable the phonebook access for your paired host device manually.

Answer (score 0):

Actually to access contacts you don't really need to access BluetoothPbapClient.java, once the device is connected for PbapClientProfile you can simply read contacts via content resolver.